# Error 500 htaccess customize for SSL

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, customization

Error 500 htaccess customize for SSL
Hello everyone, I am having problems when viewing content of my Blog in wordpress is appearing the "Error 500" - "Internal Server Error" - "Apache Server at Port 80", for the other pages. Only the home page appears normal with the green lock.

If you have another method without using CloudFlare on Hostgator tell me.

Does anyone have any solutions to this error?

Description:

- WORDPRESS
- Hostgator Server
- I'm having a Blog installation in a subdirectory "/public_html/name/".
- Plugin added Really Simple SSL.
- I have Cloudflare enabled - flexible - Pagerules = http://name.com/$1 - http://name.com/ - http://name.com/*

**- I made the Htaccess change with the code:**

```
# Redirecionamento para HTTPS 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^namefolder\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /namefolder/index.php$1 [L]

<IfModule mod_headers.c>
  <FilesMatch "\.(ttf|ttc|otf|eot|woff|woff2|font.css|css|js)$">
    Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
  </FilesMatch>
</IfModule>
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /namefolder/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /namefolder/index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Comment: Are there spaces inside this regex? `^ (. *) $`  Is there a space between the % and { in the rewrite condition?

Comment: Hello friend, there are no such spaces, it was a formatting error when attaching here.